# Multiple Activites with Recyclerview onclicks

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have searched everywhere and cannot seem to find how to to go about this, I am hoping someone can shed some light or describe to me how to go about what I am trying to achieve. I have a recyclerview adapter that I am using in multiple activities which has working onclick methods when one of the items are clicked. What I am trying to achieve though is having the onclick for each item in the recyclers in multiple activities present the user with different results.

An example of this implementation is lets say there are 3 activities, the 1st displays cars, the 2nd planes, and the 3rd boats. They all use the same adapter to display identical layouts but different information. If you clicked the first item in the cars recycler it would open a page for sedans, the first in planes would open a page for private jets, and the first of the boats would open the page for speedboats. I know how one would go about this in the use case of just one activity, but I don't know how you can use the same adapter for multiple activities to open new activites. Would you have to make a new adapter for each individual activity holding a recyclerview? This would be very helpful to know as I have many activities using the same recycler view and need to open new views or activities depending on the items chosen. I hope this example makes sense and you understand my questions.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You should make a new adapter for each recyclerview. Alternatively you could use something like `if item clicked instance of Plane open this activity`...

Comment: Are you using the same Adapter, ViewHolder and datamodel? If this is the case you could always make the viewholder abstract and create an abstract method that is called by the onclick of the item. This way you just need to implement the onclick for each item type and view logic can remain the same.

Comment: A side note. I like to have an update method in the viewholder. This way the adapter doesn't need to change (it just calls update on the viewholder) and the viewholder can implement it's own view logic.

Comment: I am using the same adapter, Viewholder and datamodel for all activities. I think I've thought of what Leo said, awhile back. When the item is clicked, check which layout the recyclerview is in and depending on which one its in, open said activity via the position? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Just to understand better, although you are reusing the RecyclerView, the data in the Views is  different right? And you just want to achieve different activity redirect when view is clicked?

Comment: The Data in the views are completely different, I know how to go about that, I just don't know how to open different views when the same position is clicked in different recyclers. (hope that makes sense)